# My Magento 2 theme not showing up in backend

Tags: magento2, theme

I hope somebody can help me out, I've tried doing it a million times again but somehow my theme doesn't show up in the backend of my Magento 2 installation. Here are my files:

**app/design/frontend/Company/default/theme.xml**

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
<title>Company Default</title> 
<parent>Magento/blank</parent> 
<media>
    <preview_image>media/preview.jpg</preview_image> <!-- the path to your theme's preview image -->
</media>
</theme>
```

**app/design/frontend/Company/default/registration.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
'frontend/Company/default',
__DIR__
);
```

**app/design/frontend/Company/default/composer.json**

```
{
  "name": "company/default",
  "description": "N/A",
  "require": {
  "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
  "magento/theme-frontend-blank": "100.0.*",
  "magento/framework": "100.0.*"
},
  "type": "magento2-theme",
  "version": "100.0.1",
  "license": [
  "OSL-3.0",
  "AFL-3.0"
],
"autoload": {
  "files": [
    "registration.php"
  ]
 }
}
```

I've cleaned the cache, added a media folder inside my themes file with a `preview.jpg` image and ran composer update, which keeps saying there is nothing to install. And cleaned the cache again. Logged in and out of my admin panel, but no luck. What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you run setup upgrade command

Answer (score 1):

Just run command for upgrade

`php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Remove var from root folder

Remove `pub/static` files and folder content.

Run command

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: I did that, and now my theme is showing up in the backend but I can't seem to change it. However, without having changed the theme my frontend is now all messed up, it is trying to load stylesheets from the luma theme with a 404 and stuff. How can this happen?

Comment: I have update my answer

Comment: Have you work above solutions

Comment: I'm currently running the last command from your updated answer. Will keep you posted, thanks so far!

Comment: Ran all of the commands but still my entire frontend is messed up since js and css are no longer loading :( @rakesh

Comment: You can try again remove pub/static folder and run deploy command again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41974/discussion-between-magin-and-rakesh).

Comment: I've ran the command again but it's still broken :(
I was able to change the theme in the backend now but it can't locate the js or stylesheets

Comment: this answer caused me all kind of issues after I removed the contents of `pub/static` - DO NOT DELETE THE `.htaccess` in that directory

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using composer I would do a `composer update` and then remove `pub/static/` and then `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` like Rakesh said in previous answer.

```
composer update
rm -r pub/static/
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

To not have it show a blank frontend once you have selected your theme you should ensure that `preview.jpg` exists.

I solved this issue on my version by ensuring that `preview.jpg` was copied from the theme I inherited from or that it is available.  Since you reference that preview.jpg file you should make sure it is in your theme directory or you will have issues.  My issue was what you described with it being a blank frontend.  Luma does have one and it also inherited from blank like your theme does here.