# Magento 2 workflow developing theme

Tags: magento2, theme

I'm in the very earlier stages of learning magento and trying to create a new theme for my client.

I'm slowly getting to grips with the cusomisations but at the moment I'm having to clear the caches, delete files and reindex to see my changes..Is there a way I can streamline this? It seems a very long winded way just to see a little change... I've put Magento in Developer mode by doing-

```
bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

And the env.php

```
'MAGE_MODE' => 'developer',
```

Does seem to make a difference though

Answer (score 1):

No, its do not make a difference.

But if in your .htaccess file defined MAGE_MODE it overrides setting from the configuration.

For .htaccess you will need set like following

**SetEnv MAGE_MODE developer**

Also, if you did run `setup:static-content:deploy` command you ned cleanup pub/static folder, because this command copy files instead make symlink

When you change to developer or production mode, we clear the contents of following directories when you change modes:

var/cache

var/di

var/generation

var/view_preprocessed

pub/static

Comment: Perfect thanks! Although now when I run the page I'm getting loads of missing files -
(index):27 GET http://localhost/m-sample/pub/static/frontend/Packt/compstore/en_US/mage/requirejs/mixins.js 
(index):21 GET http://localhost/m-sample/pub/static/frontend/Packt/compstore/en_US/css/styles-m.css 
(index):20 GET http://localhost/m-sample/pub/static/frontend/Packt/compstore/en_US/mage/calendar.css 
(index):26 GET http://localhost/m-sample/pub/static/frontend/Packt/compstore/en_US/requirejs/require.js 
+ more

Comment: Ok I seem to have seriously messed something up... Admin has lost all it's styling as well...?

Comment: You will need to delete all static content and then you will need to redeploy it again using php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: that didn't help. I also delete the htaccess file in static which seemed to be causing the problem - https://community.magento.com/t5/Theming-Layout-Design-Questions/Static-files-for-custom-theme-not-being-generated/td-p/39563

Comment: You need to restore the .htaccess file. Also, try what's recommended here:
http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/123999/18678