# Magento DevBox: run CLI commands from host vs. run bash session in container?

Tags: devbox-beta

I'm noticing some strange behaviour using Magento DevBox.

Running CLI commands from within the Docker container gives strange results (after entering `docker-compose exec --user=magento2 <service> /bin/bash` to get to a bash session, then `cd /var/www/magento2`).

It seems to have generated contents for the `pub/static` directory, which don't sync back into the host filesystem (outside Docker).

So 'adminhtml' and 'frontend' folders are currently visible in Docker via command line, but not anywhere in OSX (my host machine). I'm looking at them side by side.

**How can that happen, and where are you meant to run commands from when using DevBox?**

Comment: *Note: All I was trying to do was set up a custom front end theme on Devbox... but it falls apart for me at the first hurdle - my themes don't register or show up in the back end.
I'm pretty much following the instructions here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html*

I then began running the commands suggested in the first answer here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/123986/5196

Comment: just discovered this is probably due to this open issue: https://github.com/magento/magento2devbox-web/issues/79